# Mostrar option value mediante jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola gente buenas tardes a todos, sera que alguien me puede apoyar con un pequeño drama en jquery? tengo que mostrar un mensaje (seleccione servicio) en un select, me funciona pero me sale una vez por cada item del select jejeje, tengo este codigo jquery:

```
success:function(result){
var opciones = '';
result.data.forEach(element => {
opciones += `<option value="">--Seleccione Servicio a Asignar--</option>`; //ESTO ES LO QUE DEBO MOSTRAR UNA SOLA VEZ EN CADA CHANGE DEL SELECT
opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.servicio}</option>`;
});
$("#servicio_id").html(opciones) //aca envia los elementos al slect
}
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: Bienvenido Nicolas. Tu código funciona exactamente como es esperado, puedes explicarnos ¿Que pretendes hacer? ¿Qué comportamiento quieres obtener?¿Qué reto enfrentas?

Comment: hola estimado, si, muestra el option pero al estar dentro del for lo repite...lo que necesito es que se muestre una sola vez...

Comment: ¿Qué cosa necesitas que se muestre una sola vez? ¿Qué estás haciendo? Tú mismo dices que está dentro del for y por eso se repite, ¿Porqué no lo sacas del for? ¿Cuál es el problema si lo sacas?. Mi intención no es sonar molesto preguntándote tantas cosas o obstruir a que obtengas a una respuesta, creo que podrías ser más preciso con tu pregunta y así obtendrás una respuesta más rápida y concisa. Nosotros no sabemos cuál es el objetivo de tu código, donde está puesto, que otro código hay, cual es su aplicación, etc.

Comment: te entiendo, se que al estar dentro del ciclo se repetira por lo que tendria que imprimirlo fuera del ciclo pero no me queda del todo claro como imprimirlo fuera del ciclo y en donde deberia ir el option, esto porque el select se llena en base a la seleccion desde otro select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega el primer `option` desde el mismo `select` y borra la primer línea dentro del `foreach`, y en lugar de que los envíes con `html()` utiliza `append()` para que no te borre el primer `option`.

Tu `select` debería quedar así:

```
<select name="" id="servicio_id">
  <option value="">--Seleccione Servicio a Asignar--</option>
</select>
```

Y tu `código jquery` así:

```
success:function(result){

  var opciones = '';

  result.data.forEach(element => {
    opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.servicio}</option>`;
  });

  $("#servicio_id").append(opciones); //aca envia los elementos al slect
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tambien definir en un principio

```
var opciones = `<option value="">--Seleccione Servicio a Asignar--</option>`;
```

y dentro del for ir agregardo lo demás con el +=

```
    success:function(result) { 
       var opciones = `<option value="">--Seleccione Servicio a Asignar--</option>`;
       result.data.forEach(element => {
       opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.servicio}</option>`;
    });  
  $("#servicio_id").html(opciones)
};
```